# How to make an item bolder in description environment

Tags: environments, polyglossia, arabic, technical-environment

Does anyone know how to make an item `bolder` in description environment :

i tried to add `\textbf{ }`  like this  `\item [\textbf{{\textarabic{سورة الإخلاص }}}]`

I have the following segement of code, for example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Scheherazade}
\makeatletter

\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{2}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\Roman{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}
\setlist[enumdescript,2]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\alph{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}


\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{enumdescript}
   \item [\textbf{{\textarabic{سورة الإخلاص }}}]
    \
    \begin{itemize}
\item \textarabic{بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم} 
    \begin{itemize}
\item \textarabic{قُلْ هُوَ اللَّهُ أَحَدٌ }\hfill  \textenglish{Say, "He is Allah , [who is] One,}
\item \textarabic{اللَّهُ الصَّمَدُ}\hfill  \textenglish{Allah, the Eternal Refuge}
\item \textarabic{لَمْ يَلِدْ وَلَمْ يُولَدْ} \hfill  \textenglish{He neither begets nor is born,}
\item \textarabic{وَلَمْ يَكُن لَّهُ كُفُوًا أَحَدٌ} \hfill \textenglish{Nor is there to Him any equivalent."}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}   
\item [\textarabic{معلومات سورة}] 
    \end{enumdescript}
\end{Arabic}
\begin{Arabic}
'''سورة الإخلاص''' هي سورة [[مكية]] تتكون من 4 آيات وهي السورة رقم 112 من ترتيب سور [[القرآن الكريم]] ولها عدة فضائل إذ أن [[النبي]] يقول: ('''أيعجز أحدكم أن يقرأ ثلث القرآن في ليلة؟''') يقصد '''سورة الإخلاص'''. هي سورة تتكلم عن توحيد [[لله]] فقط وأن ليس له ولد وأنه لم يولد. وتُقرأ مع [[المعوذتين]] في معظم [[الأذكار النبوية]].
\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: I think you meant to say, “how to make an item bolder,” not “bigger.”  If that’s the case, the problem is that Scheherazade has no bold weight.  Substitute Amiri and you’ll see bold type.

Answer (score 1):

i followed the advice of [Thérèse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7883/th%C3%A9r%C3%A8se)

since Scheherazade has no bold weight i Substitute Amiri which let me see bold type.

first you have to install amiri font from [http://www.amirifont.org/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amiri/files/latest/download)

after add this to your preamble

```
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
```

instead of

```
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Instead of `\hspace` command betwwen arabic text and it's meaning, you can just use `\hfill`  .
For `RTLitems` you can just put your lists inside the `Arabic` environment to obtain RTL list